# Obtaining browser rendered HTML using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I need to obtain the groups and companies that I am following, by programmatically connecting to my LinkedIn account and scraping my profile webpage. I tried using selenium to login to LinkedIn and to obtain the rendered html of my profile webpage.

But inside the corresponding `<div>` tag `(<div id="groups-container">)` containing the list of groups I am following, I only see the JavaScript which has been used to obtain the group related information.  Is there any possibility of obtaining the fully rendered html as provided by firebug containing the list of groups.

Comment: you can get the `source code` of the page, is it what you are looking for?

Comment: I actually want the rendered html content. For example if the data is loaded by a script into a specific div, I want the loaded data inside the div rather than the script content.

Comment: of course it's possible, you only need a browser with decent JS support (so htmlunit is out of question in this matter). on the other hand linkedin has an api that can be used for such stuff. maybe you want to check it out, if it already has what you want. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs You might also want to inspect the requests in browser - direct requests are always more reliable than dealing with timing issues in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

The following Selenium code helped me in getting the list of groups I am part of. You can considering using `HTMLUnitDriver` if you dont want to see the automation on screen (headless).

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com");

// login
driver.findElement(By.id("login-email")).sendKeys("");
driver.findElement(By.id("login-password")).sendKeys("");
driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);

// navigate to Groups
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-interests"))).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='interests-sub-nav']//a[contains(.,'Groups')]")))
            .click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(10000);

// navigate to mygroups
driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Groups")).click();
Thread.sleep(10000);

// Get all groups I am part of
for (WebElement groupNameElement : driver.findElements(By.xpath(
            "//h3[contains(.,'GROUPS THAT I')][contains(.,'M IN')]/following-sibling::ul//a[@class='js-entity-name entity-name']"))) {
    System.out.println(groupNameElement.getText());
}
```